# How to allow redirection from specific domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a registration page from my website portal but I want to allow it to be loaded only if the previous domain was the PayPal domain (for example). That way I would garantee that even if a bot scanned my WordPress instance (which is not difficult), it could not register.

I know that mod_rewrite can prevent hotlinking, and allow specific domains to load that content.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ https://example/404.jpg [NC,L]`

But is it possible using a normal URL? That is, not a file, but a page?

Comment: Henrique, your question is unclear

Comment: Sorry. I want to block all the incoming traffic, except if the refer is a website like PayPal, because when the user pays for the service, it is redirected to my registration URL (which is for now public due to the system itself)

Comment: OK, but what do you mean by "normal URL, not a file, but a page" (your example should work in any case)?

Comment: It is because normally people prevent hotlinking of images and files. I want to prevent people that did not come from paypal.com to access my specific URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (assuming your registration link is, e.g. /wp-login.php?action=register)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?paypal.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=register$
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php index.php [NC,L]
```

..to redirect to index.php if someone tried to register without coming from paypal (headers can be spoofed, of course)

Comment: What does wp-login.php in the case do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the HTTP_REFERER for any URL. Add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?paypal.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/your-registration-url$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^your-registration-url$ https://website.com/404 [R=301,L]
```

That would redirect anyone visiting your registration URL not having paypal.com as the referrer to a website.com/404 or whatever page you choose to redirect them to.